# How to use string_agg with PostgreSQL in @Query annotation without nativeQuery flag?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to remove the nativeQuery flag from the @Query annotation.
The table structure may change in the future, and code without nativeQuery will make it easier to maintain later.

I have a class `Parent` that is linked to class `Child` with the @ManyToMany annotation.
Class `Child` has a field `pseudonym` that is a value of the String type.

The result of the query needs to be sorted by the String value from class `Child`, which I have to sort and then concatenate into one String value.

The query without the nativeQuery flag in the @Query annotation works if I do not add an additional sort in the string_agg function:
`order by string_agg(c.pseudonym, ',')`

If I add additional required sorting as below, an exception occurs

- `order by string_agg(c.pseudonym, ',' order by c.pseudonym)`
- `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'order' near line 1, column ...`

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "parent_child_link",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "child_id")}
    )
    @OrderBy("pseudonym ASC")
    private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String pseudonym;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "childs")
    private Set<Parent> parents = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

        @Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
            "select p.*" +
                    " from parent p" +
                    " left join parent_child_link link on p.id = link.parent_id" +
                    " left join child c on link.child_id = c.id" +
                    " where p.name = :name" +
                    " group by (p.id)" +
                    " order by string_agg(c.pseudonym, ',' order by c.pseudonym)")
    Page<Parent> find(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Comment: If you want to use native functionalities which are not supported by HQL/JPQL, you'll have to write native queries. If you would want to limit the result set, you would also end up with native query as `LIMIT` is not supported in HQL/JPQL.

Comment: The current native query visible in the @Query annotation works fine, and in the console (using the p6spy tool) at the end of the query you can see an added entry limiting the number of results `... group by (p.id) order by string_agg (c.pseudonym, ',' order by c.pseudonym) limit 20`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with nested query:

```
select p.*
from (
    select p, string_agg(c.pseudonym, ',' order by c.pseudonym) ord
    from parent p
    left join parent_child_link link on p.id = link.parent_id
    left join child c on link.child_id = c.id
    where p.name = :name
    group by (p.id)
) inn(p, ord)
order by ord
```

or:

```
select p.*
from(
    select p, c.pseudonym
    from parent p
    left join parent_child_link link on p.id = link.parent_id
    left join child c on link.child_id = c.id
    where p.name = :name
    order by p, pseudonym
) inn(p, pseudonym)
group by p.id
order by string_agg(pseudonym, ',')
```

Comment: The above queries will not help to remove the nativeQuery flag from the @Query annotation.

Comment: @GrzegorzKawalec of course it won't... You're using postgres specific functionality...